# Login with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement the following feature: whenever somebody comes to the site, he sees the login form and if he didn't logon correctly, any other url should show him login form.

how can I do this?

I have the project I inherited and only starting in Angular, so I have no idea where do I change the first page I show and how do I block unauthorized users from accessing other urls

Comment: How are you persisting the user data in the first place?

Comment: I don't yet. Later user data would be used for priviliges, but right now it's just a matter of 'is this user in our database' or not

Comment: short answer: I store logged in users as `$rootScope.loggedInUser`. I check if the user is logged in using a resolve in angular router using _input your server middleware here_ (I typically use passport) on whatever route I need protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the explanation as basic as possible angular works in the main index.html file by using "controllers" to explain to the client browser what to do.  Somewhere in your folder hierarchy should be a folder named "partials" , "templates" , "views" ,or something similar.  It should contain a bunch of small .html files.  Those files are swapped using AJAX embedded into angular.  There should be an html element tag that contains an attribute "ng-app= "whateverYourAppsNameIsHere" within the opening element tag, anything in between this tag is "angular."

Angular seems complex at first, but once you keep at it it gets much easier.  Everything within the ng-app attribute is powered in your JS files, and there's some really good free resources out there, including [codeschool](https://www.pluralsight.com/codeschool) which has one, and angular.  Google, hosts their own "phonecat app" which explains all the basics in pretty good detail in a walk-through tutorial with code snippets provided for when you can't quite figure it out.  Make sure you use this link though [Google:Angular - Go to "tutorial"] (https://angularjs.org/) There is currently an Angular 2.0, which is written in TypeScript(short hand JS) found at [FYI Only: Make sure you're not on this domain](https://angular.io/) Know this exists in the event you start liking TypeScript, but I'd recommend sticking with plain angular until you're comfortable with it.

Okay, so that's a brief splash of what's what to find your files, and hopefully help you grasp any answers a bit better.  At the very least those are 2 really good resources to start learning Angular from.

For your direct question "How do you manage users being logged in, or sending them to a page."  There are many ways to perform that task, so I'll give you guidance on how to best learn it in my opinion.  1) Review "ng-if" which you can use to display/not display a page section (or as you asked re-route to a login form if not verified)  People typically seem to use a "router" for Angular, Angular-UI is a fairly well recognized one and you can find it here: [npm angular-ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-router).  You can also verify someone on the back end when they call out to the server for page updates.

So I know I didn't directly answer your question, but the links I sent you will more than  answer your question and also give you some guidance where to start learning/looking for resources from.  If you're not yet familiar, I would recommend building/maintaining your app in Yeoman if you have not done so already.  [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) and [Yeoman - tutorial] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKiaLSJW5xI) <-- This guy is AMAZING for tutorials, and he's very reassuring when you're scratching your head feeling overwhelmed with coding things.

Hope it helps, that's 3 years worth of resources touted out in 1 question response.  Happy Coding! ;)

Comment: Thanks for such a full answer! I found config.js in which there is `... $stateProvider.state('app.home', {url: "/home"...` is written. I added in curly brackets `... loginRequered: true...` and from my controller try to use `... $location.path('/login')...` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697004/angularjs-how-to-redirect-back-to-the-next-route-after-logging-in), but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well first, did you spell "Required" correctly in your code? You have it as "Requered" here, and that won't work.  Secondly,

Comment: Well first, did you spell "Required" correctly in your code? You have it as "Requered" here and that won't work based on spelling even if you had created the correct controls.  Secondly, you don't want an additional set of curly brackets, just expand the existing curlies to include your additional "loginRequested: true" value after a comma.

From "{url: "/home" }; to 
{
url: "/home", 
loginRequired: true
});

Comment: Here is a very well worded example for AngularJS using basic HTTP auth.  http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx

Comment: Nope, I totally did all two of the things you're describing right: `.state('app.home', {
                    url: "/home",
                    templateUrl: "tpl/home.html",
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                    loginRequired: true,`

Comment: I changed in `$on` `$routeChangeStart` to `$locationChangeStart` and now it works, but my `if(nextRoute.loginRequired)` is always false for some reason